# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when releasing a copied object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, exc-bad-access

This has been killing me.. Because its a memory management issue...

I have a NSArray created like so in say Class 2

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray * sourceArray;
```

I set this array from another class say Class 1 like ...

```
Class2 = [[Class2 alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
[Class2 setSourceArray:self.namesArray];
```

Where I am sure that self.namesArray contains objects.

When I release Class 1, it releases Class 2 since Class 2 is a subview in Class 1 which is expected, but I get an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when Class 2 releases sourceArray in dealloc like so...

```
[sourceArray release];
```

I DO NOT get this error if I do not release namesArray in Class 1.. Which doesn't make sense because I am using I declared sourceArray as COPY which to my knowledge gives Class 2 its own version of the array...

Can anyone help me here? Its killing me!

More info:
The reference count right before I try to release sourcearray is 1... So Why would a release not work?!

Comment: Have you tried diagnosing your issue by using the Zombies tool in Instruments?

Comment: Don't release array in class2, may be you are using this array contains in class1

Comment: All I get when it crashes is -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2a9530
But that doesnt make sense because I copied the object from Class1 right?

Comment: If I don't release it in either of the classes I will get a leaked array using profiler.

Comment: As you said its giving -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2a9530, but sourceArray is NSArray. Are you sure the crash occurs at line [sourceArray release]; if so then may be self.namesArray is out of scope at the time when you are copying it to sourceArray. Else its because of some string you are overreleasing.

Comment: That error suggest that you over released a String that is store in that particular array.

Comment: I never release the strings though... SO strange, Its like when I release the original array in Class1 it releases all the string it contains (which is correct) but that also is releasing the Strings in Class2's array?

Comment: maybe not, but if you got an autoreleased NSString and put it in your array and in a property at the same time, but bypassing the assessor that could lead to this, but you have provided very limited code so it's just a wild guess at a possibility.

Comment: Yea looks like sometimes when I was adding strings they were getting double released (I dont actually see it doing that but I changed the way I added the arrays removing an instance of a release and that fixed it) Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which doesn't make sense because I am using I declared sourceArray as
>   COPY which to my knowledge gives Class 2 its own version of the array.

That's the idea, but it may help you to know that `-copy` often just retains the object for immutable objects. That shouldn't matter to your code, since the original is indistinguishable  from a copy for immutable objects. It may be that you're over-releasing the array in Class1, and the problem only shows up when Class2 releases it's "copy" of the array.

Comment: I dont think im over releasing in Class1 because if I dont release in dealloc I have a leaked object. I am getting -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance.. So that means When I release the array its fine, but at least one of the NSStrings it contains was over released maybe? SO like in Class1, when I release the array it is releasing each string in the array, which makes the array in class 2 contain no objects?

Comment: What I'm saying above is that in all likelihood, the array in Class2 *is* the array in Class1. That doesn't explain the problem, but it may inform your debugging. Certainly, if the message causing the error is a `release` sent to a string, that's an important clue. I'm afraid there's not much more we can say given the amount of available information. Keep at it, though... you'll find it.

Comment: Ok fixed it.. Just changed the way I added my strings to the initial array... Thanks everyone wish I could Accept you all!